# Differentiating a specific cost function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, exponential-function

Consider the following cost function.
$$J(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n [(x\,a_i+(1-x)\,b_i)-d_i]^2$$
How can I find the first and second derivatives of $J$, with respect to $x$? The variables $b_i$ are dependent on $x$, but $a_i$ and $d_i$ are independent of $x$, where $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$ and $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have to apply the chain rule for the first derivative:

$J(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ((x\cdot a_i+(1-x)\cdot b_i)-d_i)^2$

$J^{'}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2\cdot( (x\cdot a_i+(1-x)\cdot b_i)-d_i)\cdot (a_i-b_i)$

And the second derivative is

$J^{''}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2\cdot(a_i -b_i)\cdot (a_i-b_i)=2\cdot\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  (a_i-b_i)^2$

Comment: Thanks callculus. I was starting the chain rule, but didn't seem to get to it. Again, thanks.

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: I missed the first x. I´ve edited my answer.

Comment: what if x is a number between zero and 1?

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice If $x=0$, then the first derivative becomes $2\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (b_i-d_i)\cdot (a_i-b_i)$. If $x=1$, then the first derivative becomes $2\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (a_i-d_i)\cdot (a_i-b_i)$. The second derivative is not affected a by $x$.

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice Moreover if $a_i > b_i > d_i$ the first derivative is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *n* is not being sent off towards infinity, then we can differentiate the sum. Since the sum is finite, we can expand the sum:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n ((xa_i + (1 - x)b_i) - d_i)^2 = (a_1x + b_1(1 - x) - d_1)^2 + \cdots + (a_nx + b_n(1 - x) - d_n)^2.
\end{align*}

Then if we differentiate we have the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i = 1}^n ((xa_i + (1 - x)b_i) - d_i)^2 &= \frac{d}{dx}((a_1x + b_1(1 - x) - d_1)^2 + \cdots + (a_nx + b_n(1 - x) - d_n)^2)\\
&= 2(a_1x + b_1(1 - x) - d_1)(a_1 - b_1) + \cdots + 2(a_nx + b_n(1 - x) - d_n)(a_n - b_n)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n 2(a_ix + b_i(1 - x) - d_i)(a_i - b_i).
\end{align*}

Now by differentiating in the same manner, again we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i = 1}^n 2(a_ix + b_i(1 - x) - d_i)(a_i - b_i) &= \frac{d}{dx}(2(a_1x + b_1(1 - x) - d_1)(a_1 - b_1) + \cdots + 2(a_nx + b_n(1 - x) - d_n)(a_n - b_n))\\
&= 2(a_1 - b_1)(a_1 - b_1) + \cdots + 2(a_n - b_n)(a_n - b_n)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n 2(a_i - b_i)^2.
\end{align*}

If *n* is allowed to head off to infinity, this procedure may not necessarily hold.

Comment: K. Mor. n is finite, so the procedure is very helpful. thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I was assuming it was, since it was a cost function. Keep up the good work!

Comment: and what if x is a number between zero and 1? Does it change ?

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice no, it should not change. The sum will still be a finite sum. Since $0 < x < 1$ you can then talk about the constraints of your initial function and the constraints on the derivative. That is you can bound the function below by plugging in zero and bound it above by plugging in 1.

Comment: thanks @K.Mor!!

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice You are more than welcome.